# Wordpress on Django on Heroku

Tags: django, wordpress, heroku

I'm not sure if this is entirely solvable. Nevertheless, here's the problem I'm facing.

I've created a Django app deployed on heroku and then added a custom domain to the herokuapp.

This domain has it's own hosting somewhere else where a wordpress installation has been setup in a folder `/blog`. So the url to the blog in reality is `domain.com/blog`. However, after configuring the DNS to point to `appname.herokuapp.com`, the `/blog` url is understandably not working.

What should I do to fix this? Or is there a better solution, as the blog is quite an important part of the web app.

Comment: Any luck doing this? I have the same issue, mind sharing the solution?

Comment: @Javaaaa, Hey man. Yes I did solve this. It involves a couple of steps. I'll add it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following steps.

1. Installed Wordpress on a separate server (necessary since WP can't run on the same server as your django app).
2. Create a subdomain pointing to this installation using the domain control as follows `http://blog.example.com/`
3. In `views.py`, I made the following view:

   ```
   def blog(request):
       return HttpResponseRedirect('http://blog.example.com/')
   ```
4. In `urls.py`, I added the following:

   ```
   url(r'^blog', views.blog, name='blog'))
   ```
5. Your next problem is going to be that once the WP domain is hit, it'll have no static assets(CSS/JS/images). This is because they are static  pointing to `example.com/blog/wp-content`. To solve this, you'll need to add an A name record for the assets as `blog.example.com/wp-content` (Can't properly remember what the exact A name record was, but it is something on these lines)

It's a little convoluted but it works.

Comment: I tried this and it works until step 4. However, I know go to mydomain.com/blog it redirects to blog.mydomain.com. How can I make it that the URL bar will still show mydomain.com/blog?

Comment: Since `/blog` will be treated as a Django URL, the blog can't exist at that url. The only workaround which I could find was using a subdomain at blog.domain.com. Or try this method https://community.webfaction.com/questions/7912/forward-domain-with-masking-to-a-wordpress-blog-installed-on-godaddy